# Jquery Datatable change row color based on value

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

I have this jquery datatable below.
If id is 50415, I want row color to change to red. but it fails to do despite adding the css.
Tried many of the soloutions on stackoverflow. Do advise, thanks so much.

```
{
  "mDataProp": null,
  render: function (data, type, row, i) {
    var reconJrnlId = (data.jrnlItemId).toString();                 
    if (reconJrnlId === '50415') {
      console.log('change to red please');
      $(row).css("background-color","red");
    }                   
    return '-';
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle with HTML to play around with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure how your `data` is structured. But you can get the key of the data and check if the key value is your id. So then you can add the CSS this way

```
var id = data[3];
   if(id == 66){
   console.log(data);
   $(row).addClass('blue');   //add class to row
   }
```

See fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/d9m6bzyg/1/ You will see row number 2 in blue i.e. Ashton Cox

This example was take from here http://live.datatables.net/cezewiqe/1/edit